# How to let getter return a promise

Tags: javascript, django-rest-framework, javascript-objects

I want my class to return a user that I fetch from an URL.

```
export default class CurrentUser{
    get user(){
        return this.fetch_user();
    }

    fetch_user(){
        fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/current", {
            headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            Authorization: `Token ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`
            }
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then((user) => {
            return user;
        })
    }
}
```

In an another function I tried to call this class like this:

```
      const abc = new CurrentUser();
      console.log(abc.user)
```

Until now all that was returned was an empty object.
I think that when I'm calling my function fetch_user() from my getter, the function is returned before the fetch request and the promises are complete.

I tried to implement these solutions below, but I was unsuccessful at doing so.

[How to block for a javascript promise and return the resolved result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29440632/how-to-block-for-a-javascript-promise-and-return-the-resolved-result)

[How to return promise with a return value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46634304/how-to-return-promise-with-a-return-value)

[How would one do async JavaScript getters and setters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28790744/how-would-one-do-async-javascript-getters-and-setters)

Please help me.

Comment: *"How to ... return"*: by using a `return`. Your getter does not return anything.

Comment: `fetch_user` doesn't `return` anything. You need to `return fetch(...)`. That'll return a promise. Which means the getter can at best return a promise, not the user directly. There's no way around that.

Comment: ...and drop the final `.then`: it serves no purpose. Also be aware that `abc.user` will return a promise once you have that `return`. There is no way you can retrieve *now* which is only available in a *future*. You'll always need to await a promise.